# What's a proper way to control access to property that stores server call results?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

My class has a property that gets populated from a network call.  The population can be triggered by certain action.

What's the correct strategy to implement access of this property, given that the property can be accessed when a new result set is being fetched from the server?

e.g.

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *data;
@end

@implement MyClass

- (void)loadData {

  // self.data can be accessed when loadData is called.
  // What's the correct strategy for controlling access to self.data?
  [self loadDataFromServerWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *objects) {
    [self.data removeAllObjects];
    // Populate self.data with objects
  }];
}
```

Comment: So, you want your other objects get notified when load is finished in this class?

Answer (score 3):

> What's the correct strategy to implement access of this property,
>   given that the property can be accessed when a new result set is being
>   fetched from the server?

The correct strategy? Serialize access.

The easiest way is to mark the property as `atomic`, and then simply `self.data = objects;` in your completion handler.

Your completion should also do something like this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     ... tell the app to reload data ...
 });
```